# The Operating System is not generating core dump by default when an application crashes?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, fedora

I am working on Linux Fedora version :2.6.31.5.
I set the prior requirement of core dump size to "unlimit".
The problem is whenever an exception happens it is showing the message like Segementaion fault(core dumped) and other exception messages of their respect.....but it is not producing the coredump file within the directory i am working and not at all producing the core dump file in any directory of the system.
Instead, when i force the core dump generation using "gcore -o corename PID " , it is giving the coredump with name "corename.PID".
So, my question is " why is it not generating core dump by default when an application crashes ?"
If any one have the detais ,pls share it with me:)
Advance thanks to all repliers

Thanks
vlc

Comment: What is the output of `ulimit -a` for you?

Answer (score 3):

Fedora 14 generates core dumps and sends them to `abrt` for processing (on my machine). It sounds like you are running an older version of Fedora. If it is sending them to abrt, you will see

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

instead of just

```
Segmentation fault
```

if you run something that segfaults from the terminal.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-current-directory for how to configure this behaviour.